# The application exited before accepting connections. Contact the author for more information

Tags: shinyapps, py-shiny

Hi I'm deploying a shiny app using Python to shinyapps.io, the only problem is that when it opens the link, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred
The application exited before accepting connections. Contact the author for more information.
```

what am I supposed to do? Thanks for your answer